# How to write init/cleanup code for private static members in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization

With simple values, there is no problem: we simply set them in the .cpp file.

But consider the following example, that require some init/cleanup code:

```
// .h
class MyClass {
...
private:
    static unsigned First1000Primes[1000];
} ;
```

In the .cpp file, we want to initialize the array, and need some code for that.

We can define a *class Initializer* in the .cpp file, with a ctor that fills the values, and declare a *static Initializer InitAndCleanup* in the same file, so the code will run once at startup (and similarly run dtor/cleanup code if needed).

The problem with this solution is its 'messiness', as the initializer has to be a friend of MyClass to access its private parts.

So my question is: is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that like everything else, it's just a matter of encapsulation and packaging.

```
struct PrimeArray {
    PrimeArray();   // init here
    PrimeArray(PrimeArray const&) = delete;
    PrimeArray& operator=(PrimeArray const&) = delete;
    ~PrimeArray();  // cleanup here

    unsigned data[1000];
};
```

And then use that:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    // ...
private:
    static PrimeArray const primes;
};
```

And initialize in the cpp as usual:

```
PrimeArray const MyClass::primes{};
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::array` instead.

```
class MyClass {
...
private:
    static std::array<unsigned, 1000> First1000Primes;
} ;
```

Now the question of initialization is a simple lambda

```
std::array<unsigned, 1000> MyClass::First1000Primes = [&] {
    std::array<unsigned, 1000> primes;
    // fill primes
    return primes;
}();
```

Comment: Why yes it is, but there's a relatively simplistic C++03 alternative.

Comment: I was just asking cause I never saw that syntax before. :) Is it anything like Java static intializer lists?

Comment: No. It is a lambda function which I executed immediately upon definition. Lambdas are one of the biggest C++11 features- up there with variadic templates and rvalue references.

Comment: Nice, but the lambda solves half of the problem. What if I need cleanup code too?

Comment: Then I'd seriously re-consider whether a static is the right place to put this. Constants should not require cleanup. However, you can look at Matthieu's answer for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the normal way of initializing statics:

```
unsigned MyClass::First1000Primes[] = {2,3, /*...*/};
```

in the implementation file. Might I suggest you use a `std::vector` instead?

Comment: 1000 primes in a .cpp file? seriously?

Comment: @PaulOyster: why not ? That only 4KB. Of course I would seriously recommend having a dedicated cpp...

Comment: @PaulOyster I hope you're not thinking of writing this by hand... You can easily generate the file. Or you can use templates to compute the numbers at compile-time.

Comment: The only reason I gave the First1000Primes in the example was to emphasize that I need code for init/cleanup. Sorry if that was not clear.